# change the font - size responsive design

Tags: css, font-size

i have only a question. so maybe i will understand the Problem a Little bit better.

i have a Website. the font-size will be 2em (Notebook). when i check the page (Chrome Emulator) with e.g. galaxy it Looks fine. when i check it with e.g. iPad the size of font will be smaller.

So what i have to do, that font-size will we be ok for every cellphone? do i have to write for each "width" an extra media query to set the font-size?

```
#mediendesign {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #ffffff;

}
```

do i have to write for every screensize? or what can i do that it works for every Screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS 3 has units which are related to the `viewport`. such as

**vh** - for viewport height and **vw** - for viewport width

**example-**

If you define your font size like this

```
   #mediendesign {
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

it becomes 2% of your viewport width. Hence it becomes responsive.

*Whole thing is explained in detail in the article below.*

[Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Responsive web design：

CSS3 introduces a few new units, including the rem unit, which stands for "root em".The em unit is relative to the font-size of the parent, which causes the compounding issue. The rem unit is relative to the root—or the html—element. That means that we can define a single font size on the html element and define all rem units to be a percentage of that. as a result,you can code like the following(based on 750px):

```
 /* 10px === 1rem, the default font-size of html-element is 16px  */
 html {font-size: 62.5%;/*10 ÷ 16 × 100% = 62.5%*/}
 /* The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices. */
 @media (min-width:640px) and (max-width: 999px) {

       /* 750/640 = 1.17*/

        html{font-size: 53.42%;}  /*62.5% / 1.17 */

  }

 @media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width:450px){

      /*  750 / 400 = 1.875 */

     html{font-size:33.33% } /* 62.5% / 1.875 */

  }

  @media (min-width:360px) and (max-width: 399px) {

       /*  750 / 360 = 2.08 */

      html{font-size:30%}   /* 62.5% / 2.08  */

  }

 @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:359px){

      /*  750/320 = 2.34 */

     html{font-size: 26.7%}  /* 62.5 / 2.34 */

 }
```

[image: resolutions]

```
#mediendesign {
font-size: 2rem;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

if I assume that your ipad resolution is 768*1024, and`font-size: 2rem;`. so the  final rendering result:

```
  #mediendesign {
  font-size: 17.0944px;/* (53.42%/62.5%)*10px*2rem=17.0944px */
  color: #ffffff;
  }
```

in the end,you can adjust`html{font-size: xx%}` to meet your requirement.